# Android: Listen to network set timezone event

Tags: android

I had to find out a way to differentiate between timezone being set by a user or via network nitz protocol. I had to dig around the Android sources and came up with this idea. I will post it just in case someone else needs it. No need to lose time on this.

Also, if you have a better way of doing it, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

```
final String NITZ_ACTION = "android.intent.action.NETWORK_SET_TIMEZONE";

IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(NITZ_ACTION);
this.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();            
        if (NITZ_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            //Do whatever you need to do
        }
    }
}, intentFilter);
```